# Ignore errors when updating links in Excel

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file with over 100 sources. When I go edit links, select them all and go update it stops for prompt if it finds that source file is missing. Is there any way that I can skip that, so it will ignore the prompt and just update links that Excel can find?

[image]

Comment: Do you want them to just update on startup or manually while using the file? If it's on startup, then clicking "Startup Prompt" lets you choose to update the links without alerts.

Comment: That's not the point. When I click update it stops on broken links. I would like to just pass them not to prompt for file.

Comment: What happens it you click "refresh all" under the Data ribbon?

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

Comment: @Mobus nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Skip problem files temporarily**

1. Click "Check Status"
2. Sort list by status by click on the "status" header
3. Select all files **without** errors
4. Click "Update Values"

**Fix problem files permanently**

1. Click "Check Status"
2. Sort list by status by click on the "status" header
3. Select all files **with** errors
4. Click "Break Link"

> Ps. Once you break the link, it cannot be undone. If the missing files come back (e.g. from a network share), the links cannot be reinstated. Save a backup.

Comment: And how to stop prompt for missing files? I wanna just to skip them.

Comment: If you follow the instructions for "Skip problem files temporarily", you will no longer have the prompt.